# How to allow ESLint work with multiple <script> tags in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, eslint, eslintrc

Imagine this simplified code snippet:

```html
<template>
  <div>Your number is {{number}}</div>
</template>

// since script setup tag doesn't allow for exports this is allowed. 
// I use it to create a pinja store that can be exported.
<script lang="ts">
  export const x = 10;
</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const props = defineProps({
    nr: Number
  })

  const number = props.nr * x;
</script>
```

**After linting**

This is a valid syntax, except ESLint seems to automatically move the exported value into the  `<script setup>` tag:

```html
<script lang="ts"> 
  // This stays empty
</script>

<script setup lang="ts">
  export const x = 10; //this gives an error
  const props = defineProps({
     nr: Number
  })

  const number = props.nr * x;
</script>
```

which gives an error as in Vue3 you cannot export from `<script setup>`.

How can I disable ESlint for automatically moving this code around, and how can I disable for export errors in `vue`files?!

Comment: What do you want to do here exactly? You can't use exports here because script setup is already doing that for you.

Comment: If you look at the code snippets, you'll see that after linting the `export const x = 10` has been moved out of the `<script lang="ts">` and automatically put into `<script setup lang="ts">` by ESLint. This give an syntax error. 

The reason I want `x` to be exported, is that I want to import and use it somewhere else. Note that `x` is just a simplified code for a `Pinja Store`.

Comment: Isn't that a Volar feature?

Comment: No, I had Volar on this project without causing this sort of issue. I figured out the problem (see the answer), but I appreciate your initiative :)

Comment: I am having the same problem, but I am not using @vue/eslint-config-airbnb 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit causing this headache was actually the `@vue/eslint-config-airbnb` extension. Removing this extension fixed the mentioned issue, although it allso removed some airbnb defined rules I would want to have kept.